# Is there a way to renew a DHCP lease for another client?

Tags: dhcp

I am looking for a way to renew a DHCP lease for ANOTHER client, that the one making the request. I know how to do this for the requesting client using `dhclient` or `arping`, but I have this old router that does not have static ip per mac address setting, and a network printer that changes an ip with each reset...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you wish to have a client execute a DHCP LEASE RENEWAL from a trigger sent by another client.  In terms of security, clients shouldn't be allowed to control other clients on the network.  The DHCP server could send a FORCERENEW message to all clients but that would force all clients to renew and few DHCP Servers even support this.  https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3203.txt.

- Targeting a specific client from another client can be accomplished using exploitation techniques such as  MITM attack, DHCP Server Spoofing, etc.. to perform Remote Code Execution or Denial of Service for the specific client.
  https://www.whitewinterwolf.com/posts/2017/10/30/dhcp-exploitation-guide/
- I take it that the old router you are using is also serving as the DHCP server.  A simple solution would be to lower the Default Leas Time and/or Max Lease Time as doing so would have the client request the Renewal after the time specified.
- Being that your router is old, another solution would be to replace the router firmware with one capable of assigning static IP addresses to MAC addresses such as DD-WRT, OpenWRT, Tomato, etc...
  https://dd-wrt.com/ 
  https://openwrt.org/docs/start 
  http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato

Comment: I can confirm this after some more research - messing with others DHCP leases should not be possible, and probably is not. I've solved the issue with a router firmware upgrade.